# Apache Parallel Path Document Root

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have a website set up in apache2 (Windows 7), say my DocumentRoot is /mysite/content

but I also have includes in a parallel directory, say /mysite/lib

so my index.php file says:

```
require_once("/mysite/lib/myfile.php");
```

but it won't find the file because it takes it from the document root.  so it is looking for

```
/mysite/content/mysite/lib/myfile.php instead of /mysite/lib/myfile.php
```

and I can't make the root /mysite because the files included are referring to the root, mysite/content.  any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Do you have try without the first slash?

Comment: Always use relative paths when requiring. Otherwise your code can never be moved!

Comment: well, this is a large site, and they are absolute, so can't really change

Comment: @Sam, without the first slash it adds the path to the server root, and apache errors because there is no file.

Comment: it seems to work in linux, does linux also check the root directory as well as the DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the include path in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

When including try to use a fully qualified path name, that way you will never hit those problems while requiring php files. You can use the `__DIR__` constant in conjunction with realpath in order to establish kind of a root directory and then including what you need.

Let's assume the root dir is something/public and you want to include from something/libs. Assuming you are in index.php from something/public you would do the following:

```
$rootPath = realpath(__DIR__ . "/../");
require_once $rootPath . "/libs/somefile.php";
```

I think this should help your problem. On *nix systems beware of the fact that you need apache to have rights onto the libs directory in order to read from there.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of this answer is finding the current index.php position and determining the base path of your application, then by using that base path, addressing anything in your application relatively and easily.

You can get the information from php: The exemplary paths below are for an xampp server setup, you may(probably) get different results but they(I hope) will be correct.

```
$path = str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__));
```

this will give you server relative path for index.php which is for example:
'd:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/content'

then you can remove 'content' by

```
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path,'/')+1);
```

now you will have something like which is your application root:

'd:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/'

now you can access lib by just saying:

```
require_once($path.'lib/myfile.php');
```

hope this is helpful.

Comment: And I really hope that I did not misunderstood your question. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your php.ini.

Create a file in your webroot called phpinfo.php with the content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

And nothing else.  Save it and then load it in your web browser, you are looking for two things

1. safe_mode
2. open_basedir

If safe_mode is on, turn it off.  If open_basedir is anything other than none, set it to none.  If you can't edit your php.ini for whatever reason, you may be able to set this in a .htaccess with:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

**Sources**:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-include-dir
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, before calling `require_once("myfile.php");`:

```
$base  = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
$paths = array(
    $base . '/mysite/lib',
    '.',
    get_include_path()
);

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
```